# Pandas calculate new column by splitting off optional leading non-string characters

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

I'm new to Pandas and attempting to add TWO new columns with values calculated from an existing 'Result' column.

The existing column includes numbers with an optional qualifier ('<', '>', '<>').

Some sample numbers in the 'Result' might be:

```
0.5
12.67
3
<1
4.5
>10.0
```

I want a new 'Result_Q' column that includes the non-numeric qualifier, if it exists and NULL (None) otherwise and a new 'Result_Value' column that includes the numeric component.

My first attempt that does not work is:

```
df['Result_Q'] = df.Result.str[0] if not df.Result.str[0].isdigit() else None
```

This produces the error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isdigit'`

(After researching this error I've tried a few other variations which produce 
 `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Result_Q'] = np.where(df.Result.str[0].str.isdigit(), None, df.Result.str[0])
```

Alternative with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Result_Q'] = df.Result.str[0].mask(df.Result.str[0].str.isdigit(), None)

print (df)
  Result Result_Q
0    0.5     None
1  12.67     None
2      3     None
3     <1        <
4    4.5     None
5  >10.0        >
```

Or [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with change `NaN` to `None`:

```
df['Result_Q'] = df.Result.str[0].str.extract('(\D)').mask(lambda x: x.isna(), None)
print (df)
  Result Result_Q
0    0.5     None
1  12.67     None
2      3     None
3     <1        <
4    4.5     None
5  >10.0        >
```

Comment: This method with `np.where()` works for me.  Thanks!  I had tried something similar to this before, but using `.str[0].str` instead of just `.str[0]` is what I was missing.  I need to go back to the Pandas documentation and understand this better now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `df.apply` to create the new column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'result': ['0.5', '12.67', '<1', '4.5', '>10.0']})
df['Result_Q'] = df['result'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if not x[0].isdigit() else None)
print(df)


  result Result_Q
0    0.5     None
1  12.67     None
2     <1        <
3    4.5     None
4  >10.0        >
```

Comment: This seems to work.  I need to understand a bit more about what it's doing (being a Pandas newbie).

Comment: It 'applies' the lambda function to each row in the column 'result'. And the lambda function does exactly the same what you did in the 'if'.

Comment: @L3n95 - I suggest dont use `apply` here if need general solution, because it failed if `NaN`s in `result` column. If 100% sure never contains missing values, is possible use it.

Comment: @jezrael yes that's right, but that's not directly a problem of the apply, but of the `if` in the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Or try:

```
df['Result_Q'] = df['Result'].str.replace('\d+', '').str.strip('.').replace('', np.nan)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Result Result_Q
0    0.5      NaN
1  12.67      NaN
2      3      NaN
3     <1        <
4    4.5      NaN
5  >10.0        >
```